# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView when starting activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I am trying out recyleview in android for the first time. 
I followed this tutorial 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

The app is fresh and only contains this one activity. The goal for now is just to display a list of strings using the recyleview.
The app compiles, but if I launch it(on a virtual device api 26), it crashes with the error.

I have tried launching with API lvl 26 and 28. I also tried changing the version of the support libarys, but that completly destroyed my first app...

I have read trough a lot of google results which touch on the problem. But they all seem to have different very specific causes. Which I could not apply to my problem.

My Dependincies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

My Activity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private val myArray = arrayOf("Hans","Klaus")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = MyAdapter(myArray)
        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recycler_view).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }
    }
}
class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: Array<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(val textView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false) as TextView
        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

The caused by portion of the error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-O0jrBUQE1V6V1rEdCmyGrg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
```

Comment: RecyclerView is now part of AndroidX packages . try to use androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is probably caused because you are using androidx (see your imports), but in your gradle file you have included android.support, so to fix this you should make following changes:

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

to

`androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0`

Also make sure to make change into your xml file, instead:

`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>`

use

`<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>`

**EDIT:**

RecyclerView version might change so always check for newest

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It solved my problem. I am wrestling with others errors now, but they seem less abstract to me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`RecyclerView` is now part of `AndroidX` package . 
try to use `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` instead

Just use this dependency

```
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: Thank for your quick answer it also got me on the right track, but I gave FilipRistic the aceptance, as he also included the hint about also updating the xml file.